# UIView not appearing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

So I have this code -

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.searchController = [[PlacesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlacesView" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"TEXT FIELD DID BEGIN EDITIN");
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.searchController animated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

The `NSLog` runs, but my view doesn't appear. This is happening in a controller that has a view that exists in the navigation bar. Like this -

```
-(void)addSearchBar{
    self.searchBarController = [[SearchBarController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SearchBar" bundle: nil];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarController.view;
}
```

where addSearchBar is called in the `initWithNibName` method.

Why is my view not appearing?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        searchQuery = [[SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery alloc] init];
        searchDetailQuery = [[SPGooglePlacesPlaceDetailQuery alloc] init];
        searchQuery.radius = 2000;
        shouldBeginEditing = YES;
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I've also proven that the view works because when I do this -

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.searchController = [[PlacesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlacesView" bundle:nil];
    //may have to be strong.
    NSLog(@"SELF VIEW : %@", self.view);
    textField.inputView.center = self.view.center;
    textField.inputView.bounds = self.view.bounds;
    textField.inputView = self.searchController.view;
}
```

The view appears in place of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the addSearchBar from `initWithNibName` to `viewDidLoad` for a try. In fact, usually in the `init` method, the view doesn't initialize. The view will be lazily initialize when it is first access, usually when you show the view on the screen, and the `viewDidLoad` method will be call immediately after the view is initialized. So usually the `init` method only configure data related property, and the view related property usually configured in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Which view didn't appear? The view of PlacseViewController? Can you see the push animation?

Comment: And does the viewDidAppear method in the PlacesViewController invoke?

Comment: er the view of the PlacesViewController did not appear - the viewDidAppear method is not being called

Comment: OK, did you mean that if you remove the 'addSearchBar' method, the view will appear? If so, how about move the 'addSearchBar' method into 'viewWillAppear' or 'viewDidAppear'?

Comment: I meant if I move the addSearchBar method to the viewDidLoad method - I can see a search bar in the nav bar

Comment: Oh, can you show your initWithNibName method in PlacesViewController?

Comment: just added it to the question

Comment: OK, but I still want to know that if you remove the 'addSearchBar' method, can you see the view then?

Comment: if I remove the search bar, then there's nothing to click, so why would the view appear? I've proven there's nothing wrong with the initWithNibName method(just edited to tell you why)

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstand your problem. I think the addSearchBar method is called in the initWithNibName method of PlaceViewController. And does the viewDidLoad method of POlaceViewController is being called?

Comment: And did you mean that the delegate of search bar is the SearchBarController? I think the navigationController in the SearchBarController is nil. You should call the pushViewController method in the top view controller.(The controller that call the addSearchBar method)

Comment: Now that there are 3 view controllers. One is the controller that call 'addSearchBar' method, just call it currentViewController, another is SearchBarController, and the other is PlaceViewController. I notice that you didn't set the delegate of the search bar in the addSearchBar method, so maybe the delegate of the search bar is the SearchBarController. However, the navigationController property of the SearchBarController is nil because you just add the view of SearchBarController to the currentViewController. So you can't push the PlaceViewController in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method.

Comment: You should call the [self.navigationController pushViewController] method in the currentViewController. To do so, you can set the delegate of the search bar to the currentViewController and move the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method to the currentViewController.